# Need help finding (linux compatible) source code for 'pathchar' program

Tags: linux, unix, bsd

Am unable to locate the source for pathchar (Van Jacobson's wonderful hack - http://www.caida.org/tools/utilities/others/pathchar/) inspite of searching over many places. What happened to it and is it still part of some obscure package on linux?

Please help me find the latest source for pathchar.

Thanks!

EDIT: pathchar isn't around; [this page](http://www.caida.org/tools/taxonomy/perftaxonomy.xml) mentions an alternative called clink. Found the source for clink on github.com/AllenDowney/clink

Answer (score 1):

The page [here](http://www.caida.org/tools/taxonomy/perftaxonomy.xml) suggests that there is no source code available for pathchar

> ... No source code available

However, the page also lists [clink](http://github.com/AllenDowney/clink) as a

> A reimplementation of pathchar...
>
> Source freely downloadable.

Perhaps it or one of the other tools on the page will help you.

There is also an email address on the page you link to for the page maintainer - perhaps they can help.

Comment: Thanks; the page for clink is throwing an HTTP 403 (forbidden). :(

Comment: @megazoe: Well contact it's author his email is listed on the first page I linked to.

Comment: Hadn't noticed the first page given; found the source for clink on github now. Thanks